# Why can I not add a reference to a project in Visual Studio 2012 and 2015?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, I create a new project, using the Visual C# > Windows > Console Application template.  (The target framework is the default of .NET Framework 4.5.2, but I do not think that is relevant to the problem.)

I attempt to add a reference to the project.  In the Solution Explorer, I expand the project, right-click on “References”, and click the “Add Reference…” context menu item, which launches the “Reference Manager” dialog.  In the dialog, under Assemblies > Extensions,  I select the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly whose version is 14.0.0.0, and click the OK button.

Nothing happens.  The assembly I selected is not added as a reference to the project.

I have the same problem if I select **any** assembly.  None of them are added as a reference to the project.

I have the same problem if I use Visual Studio 2012.  (The target framework is .NET Framework 4.6.1.)

I do **not** have the problem if I use Visual Studio 2008.  (The target framework is .NET Framework 3.5, and the versions of the assemblies are also older.)  But, at least I can add an assembly as a reference to the project.  Once again VS2008, my favorite, wins the day!  Unfortunately, I will be compelled to develop with VS2015.

What can I possibly be doing wrong in a newly created project that would prevent an assembly from being added as a reference to the project?

Comment: The fact other developers don't have such problems suggests the problem is only on your machine.  Have you tried repairing the installation? Or installing a fresh version like VS 2017 or better yet, VS 2019?

Comment: The version of the Interop and the version of Microsoft Office has to be the same.

Comment: @jdweng: That is a good point;  I will investigate whether the Office I have agrees with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly.  However, the larger problem of why I cannot add **any** assembly as a reference remains puzzling.

Comment: I wondering if the type of project (x86 or x64) is not compatible with the interop you are installing.

Comment: Did you try to install it by `Project -> Manage Nuget Packages...`?